# How can i get return value from another app by using universal link in IOS?

Tags: flutter

How can I get return value from another app by using universal link especially in IOS?

Is it any function / library?

When I use URL launcher to open another app, how can I get the result / value back? As I am using payment, need to redirect from another payment app.

As I am not familiar with IOS, I have searched for some similar function in IOS, but I didn't find it.

I am trying to find [App extension](https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/), is it a similar solution?

Comment: have you seen https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/ios/app-extensions?

Comment: yes, but i don't know which part is suitable, do you mean i should use app group function?